# Alter colnames in a dataframe subset

Tags: r

I want to add a suffix to colnames in a dataframe, why the approach I use does not work?

```
a = 1:8
b = 1:8
c = c(-1, -2, 0, 1, 2, 6, 10, 11)
ID<-rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each=2)
df<-data.frame(ID, a,b,c)
colnames(df[,2:ncol(df)]) <- paste(colnames(df[,2:ncol(df)]),"[-]", sep = " ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put the index of column out like this

```
colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)] <- paste(colnames(df[,2:ncol(df)]),"[-]", sep = " ")
```

I think this is related to the in-place modification mechanism of R, when you write `df[,2:ncol(df)]`, it refers a temporary object instead of `df` itself (?).